# Save .jpg files into folders with the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename

I'm trying to save .jpg files one by one into folders that have the same name.

```
For example:
012454.jpg into folder 012454
000767.jpg into folder 000767
```

I've already created the folders but I cannot change the path of the images using a loop

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filename = filename[:-4]
    os.mkdir(filename)
```

Comment: Do you want to create the folders while your script working or something else?

Comment: while it is working. thanks